# Ipstack Responses are 'undefined' and the documentation does not explain why?

Tags: jquery, json, ip-geolocation

I've done all of the steps in setting up a ip-to-geolocation by using [ipstack.com](https://ipstack.com), and read through the [documentation](https://ipstack.com/documentation). But the object values are returned as 'undefined' in my browser console. This is how the code looks:

```
var ip = '188.124.3.1';
var access_key = 'secret';
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.ipstack.com/' + ip + '?access_key=' + access_key,   
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        var city = json.city;
        var zip = json.zip;
        var latitude = json.latitude;
        var longitute = json.longitute;
        console.log(city + ' ' + zip + ' ' + latitude + ' ' + longitute);
        console.log('success!');
        //the code reaches this stage, but returns as 'undefined' for each value above
        //execute a second ajax function to insert the values into a database.
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "insert_geolocation.php",
            data: {
                    'zip': zip,
                    'lat': latitude,
                    'lng': longitute
                    },
            success: function (data) {
                // it's successful, do nothing else.
                // the code also reaches this stage, but the database gets a row with NULL and 0 as values...So the response from the API is returning undefined, for an unknown reason.
            },
        });
    },
    error: function(html, data) {
        console.log('Error!');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I'm using jQuery and the JSON output from the documentation, because I'm not really clued up with CURL. Can anyone tell me exactly why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this was because I was on a free subscription plan, and that doesn't offer going through 'ssl'. Just print the json like so: `console.log(json)` inside the success function, and see which error it gives you.

Comment: I suggest looking at [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co). It is fast, reliable and inexpensive. HTTPs is supported along with all features. We do not ask more for features that cost us nothing! You start with 100,000 free lookups (disclaimer: I run the service).